# PHP outputting text WITHOUT echo/print?

Tags: php, html, output

From tuxradar.com:

Example 1:

```
<?php
    if ($foo == $bar) {
        print "Lots of stuff here";
        print "Lots of stuff here";
        print "Lots of stuff here";
        ...[snip]...
        print "Lots of stuff here";
        print "Lots of stuff here";
    }
?>
```

Example 2:

```
<?php
    if ($foo == $bar) {
?>
    Lots of stuff here
    Lots of stuff here
    Lots of stuff here
    ...[snip]...
    Lots of stuff here
    Lots of stuff here
<?php
    }
?>
```

Assume `$foo` = `$bar`.

The output is equal on both of them. I don't understand why. Example 2 has no `print`/`echo`, as far as I understand that bunch of words should not be understood by the PHP parser without `print` or `echo`. So why does it actually get printed when that 'bunch of wards' is seperated by another set of `<?php ?>` tags, when it normally wouldn't?

I think I'm missing something here that I would like to understand to the core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that Example 2 outputs the text is because you have closed the PHP tag. The browser is rendering/interpreting it as plain text. You could also format the text output with HTML and it would render nicely in the browser.

Comment: @frrlod: This is a very common practice and can lead to _very nice_ looking code.  If you need variables output in the plain HTML, consider doing so like this: `<?= $variable ?>`, or `<?php echo $variable; ?>`. It's all about readability.

Comment: @Kristy The server is interpreting it as plain text. The browser doesn't read PHP anyways.